# Xperia Arc S typing problem while connected to PC?

Tags: usb, keyboard, sony-xperia-arc

I am having a problem with my Xperia Arc S, running Android v4.0.3. When I connect my phone to PC with USB cable, and trying to type anything while it's connected, my phone detects a single touch as a multiple random touches (e.g., I press "w", and it writes "wgjr4"), and when I'm trying to delete errors, it deletes one letter and again types several. It's annoying, and there's gotta to be some solution.

Can anybody tell me where is the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: This is _only_ when connected via USB? Are you using the standard keyboard?

Comment: Do you use a self-powered usb hub (with a bad power source)? Bad rippled power supplies may distort the touch screen inputs (for capacitive touch sensors). If not, try a self powered hub and see if it's better... (if your pc pwr supply is causing this)

Answer (score 0):

Yup even I have a Xperia NEO had I have also faced the same issue. I tried reporting it on the [Sony Mobile forum](http://communities-origin.sonyericsson.com/thread/36293) but it seems it is a unresolved bug. Seems the issue is with the current supply, which makes the screen too sensitive resulting in multi-touch. Try disconnecting and try typing after sometime, seems to help in my case.